# Fixing a wooden brace that has had holes drilled in it

Tags: wood, garage, beam, hole-repair

When putting up my punch bag in the garage I drilled holes which I have decided need to be sealed post conversation in another question raised by myself.

There are 2 holes running along the brace approximately 8cm apart and 6-8cm deep with 1cm diameter.

One person mentioned using a combination of hard wooden dowels with strong wood glue. There was also recommendation of bracing the beam on one or both sides.

There is a little loft for storing bits and pieices above with floor boards. Nothing heavy is up there but I can't speak for future owners.

I have tried to include an image but SE is returning error: "access_token must be set". I will try again later.

What is the most effective way of 'fixing' these holes?

Comment: Is there something wrong with gluing in a dowel?

Comment: I ordered wooden dowels and glue.